# JBoss- JMS - Failed to download and/or install client side AOP stack

Tags: jboss, jms, messaging, jndi

When tried to build a JMS Client to get a connection to messaging on JBoss5(default configuration), I encounter this error(at line: Connection conn = qcf.createQueueConnection();). This is maven project with following libraries in classpath.

```
jboss:jnp-client:jar:4.0.2:compile
jboss:jboss-aop:jar:JBOSSAS-5.1:compile
jboss:jboss-messaging-client:jar:1.4.7.GA:compile
jboss:jbossall-client:jar:JBOSSAS-5.1:compile
jboss:jboss-common-core:jar:JBOSSAS-5.1:compile
jboss:jboss-mdr:jar:JBOSSAS-5.1:compile
jboss:jboss-logging-spi:jar:JBOSSAS-5.1:compile
org.jboss.remoting:jboss-remoting:jar:2.5.3.SP1:compile
```

For a very simple code this did not make sense. Any help is appreciated.

My code is as following:

```
    Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
    env.put(Context.OBJECT_FACTORIES, "ConnectionFactory");
    env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

    InitialContext iniCtx = new InitialContext(env);

    Object tmp = iniCtx.lookup("java:/XAConnectionFactory");

    QueueConnectionFactory qcf = (QueueConnectionFactory) tmp;
    Connection conn = qcf.createQueueConnection();
```

The error I was getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to download and/or install client side AOP stack
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(JBossConnectionFactory.java:199)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:101)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(JBossConnectionFactory.java:95)
    at com.test.JMSExample.main(JMSExample.java:120)
Caused by: org.jboss.jms.exception.MessagingNetworkFailureException: Failed to connect client
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.createClient(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:347)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.org$jboss$jms$client$delegate$ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate$getClientAOPStack$aop(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:246)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.getClientAOPStack(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.ClientAOPStackLoader.load(ClientAOPStackLoader.java:75)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.JBossConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(JBossConnectionFactory.java:192)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.loadClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:460)
    at org.jboss.remoting.InvokerRegistry.createClientInvoker(InvokerRegistry.java:359)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client$6.run(Client.java:724)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:720)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.connect(Client.java:668)
    at org.jboss.jms.client.delegate.ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.createClient(ClientConnectionFactoryDelegate.java:343)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors.mapJavaBeanProperties(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/Properties;Z)V
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.mapJavaBeanProperties(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:1359)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.setup(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:533)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.MicroSocketClientInvoker.<init>(MicroSocketClientInvoker.java:292)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker.<init>(SocketClientInvoker.java:78)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.BisocketClientInvoker.<init>(BisocketClientInvoker.java:166)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.bisocket.TransportClientFactory.createClientInvoker(TransportClientFactory.java:44)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is a mismatch between JAR files or connectivity problem. Try to do following steps:

1) set `-verbose:class` option of JVM running JBoss AS and examine the output to find where `MicroSocketClientInvoker.class` comes from, it looks like JBoss couldn't find a method from it.

2) check if port `4457` is opened, because JBoss messaging connector uses default serverBindPort on 4457.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That is true. We had an older version of "org.jboss.util.propertyeditor.PropertyEditors" which did not have the method it was looking for. Old one was taking precedence over the new libraries we have added. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Pradeep, so how did you narrow the problem down? Have you tried to set `-verbose:class`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The issue can be caused by several underlying root causes. In order to evaluate your specific root cause you need to look at the exception stack trace all the way down the "Caused by" exception the to root exception.

In my case the problem was caused by a truststore certificate file that had been corrupted due to incorrectly filtering it during processResources taks of my gradle project. Binary files get corrupted when they are filtered during processResources. For me the fix was to exclude the my certificate.truststore file from resource filtering.